# Python 2.7 ImportError: no module named _ssl

Tags: python, python-2.7, openssl

I'm trying to build python 2.7 in Redhat with SSL. I've uncommented out the lines in Modules/Setup.dist:

```
SSL=/urs/local/ssl
_ssl _ssl.c
-DUSE_SSL -I$(SSL)/include -I$(SSL)/include/openssl
-L$(SSL)/lib -lssl -lcrypto
```

and I've ensured that OpenSSL is installed on the system, as well as openssl-devel.

Prior to installing `openssl-devel` after running make it would complain that it could not build the module `_ssl`. That error is now gone. Make successfully builds `_ssl.o` with no errors reported in the log, but does not build `lib-dynload/_ssl.so` - this is apparently the file that I need to get ssl to work. I'm running `./configure` with the `--enable-shared` flag, but so far no matter how I alter the build environment, I can't get that library file to load.

Comment: Do you have `python-openssl` or something similar installed? I have it on my Ubuntu, not sure if you need it for Redhat.

Comment: I do have python-openssl installed as well.

Comment: Did you run `make clean` and `.configure` after installing openssl-devel? On my system (Ubuntu) I did not have to edit `Modules.Setup.dist` for `_ssl.so` to get compiled and installed, so I wonder why you did that.

Answer (score 0):

> Make successfully builds _ssl.o with no errors reported in the log,
>   but does not build lib-dynload/_ssl.so - this is apparently the file
>   that I need to get ssl to work.

I don't know about the details of building Python, but on Red Hat you might need to build OpenSSL with:

```
$ export CFLAGS="-fPIC"
$ ./config shared -no-ssl2 -no-ssl3 --openssldir=/usr/local/ssl ...
...
$ make depend
...
$ make all
...
$ sudo -E make install
```

After you make install, be sure sure the shared objects are in `/usr/local/ssl/lib`. I've encountered the "missing shared objects" on Fedora, and the above fixed the issue for me.